# Sum two rows from Same column within same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column called price. I have two rows in that column. How do is subtract row2-row1

Table = table1
It has columns name, price
Price column has values as

```
Name      price
pen        123.24
pencil     2345.6
```

How to subtract two rows from price column (2345.6-123.24) using sql query.

The output should be like 2222.36.

This is obtained by subtracting 2345.6-123.24

Comment: You need a way to define the order of your rows. Or you could use LEAD/LAG and ABS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT(r2.price - r1.price) AS total1
FROM table r1 CROSS JOIN
     table r2
WHERE t1.name = 'pen' AND t2.name = 'pencil';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the "name" of value that must be subtracted, you could do

```
Select sum(case when name = 'pen' then price * -1 else price end) from table
```